# Not waiting for threads to end

Tags: python-2.6

I have a script that handles threads.

Is it wrong if I don't wait for my threads to end with [`threading.thread.join`](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join)? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not wrong to not wait if you don't care whether or not they complete. Sometimes you may end up with a hanging python process you have to kill afterwards.

It is however best practise to wait on them to prevent your system from endlessly spawning threads and possibly consuming all your system's resources.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily have to wait for threads you make to end with join. It depends what you're doing. Join is simply a way to wait for the thread to end. If you had 4 threads that each do 1/4 of some task, and you want to know when the task is done, you would use join.